# Proper signature for a function accepting an iterator of strings

Tags: rust

I'm confused about the proper *type* to use for an iterator yielding string slices.

```rust
fn print_strings<'a>(seq: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>) {
    for s in seq {
        println!("- {}", s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arr: [&str; 3] = ["a", "b", "c"];
    let vec: Vec<&str> = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
    let it: std::str::Split<'_, char> = "a b c".split(' ');

    print_strings(&arr);
    print_strings(&vec);
    print_strings(it);
}
```

Using `<Item = &'a str>`, the `arr` and `vec` calls don't compile. If, instead, I use `<Item = &'a'a str>`, they work, but the `it` call doesn't compile.

Of course, I can make the Item type generic too, and do

```rust
fn print_strings<'a, I: std::fmt::Display>(seq: impl IntoIterator<Item = I>)
```

but it's getting silly. Surely there must be a single canonical "iterator of string values" type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR The signature you use is fine, it's the callers that are providing iterators with wrong `Item` - but can be easily fixed.

As explained in the other answer, `print_string()` doesn't accept `&arr` and `&vec` because `IntoIterator` for `&[T; n]` and `&Vec<T>` yield *references* to `T`. This is because `&Vec`, itself a reference, is not allowed to consume the `Vec` in order to move `T` values out of it. What it can do is hand out references to `T` items sitting inside the `Vec`, i.e. items of type `&T`. In the case of your callers that don't compile, the containers contain `&str`, so their iterators hand out `&&str`.

Other than making `print_string()` more generic, another way to fix the issue is to call it correctly to begin with. For example, these all compile:

```
print_strings(arr.iter().map(|sref| *sref));
print_strings(vec.iter().copied());
print_strings(it);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=434dadab205f53ae4c378b7dac579107)

`iter()` is the method provided by slices (and therefore available on arrays and `Vec`) that iterates over references to elements, just like `IntoIterator` of `&Vec`. We call it explicitly to be able to call `map()` to convert `&&str` to `&str` the obvious way - by using the `*` operator to dereference the `&&str`. The `copied()` iterator adapter is another way of expressing the same, possibly a bit less cryptic than `map(|x| *x)`. (There is also `cloned()`, equivalent to `map(|x| x.clone())`.)

It's also possible to call `print_strings()` if you have a container with `String` values:

```
let v = vec!["foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()];
print_strings(v.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()));
```

Comment: Oh, it's right [there in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied), too: "useful when you have an iterator over `&T`, but you need an iterator over `T`". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The error you are seeing is expected because `seq` is `&Vec<&str>` and `&Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator` with `Item=&T`, so with your code, you end up with `Item=&&str` where you are expecting it to be `Item=&str` in all cases.

The correct way to do this is to expand `Item` type so that is can handle both `&str` *and* `&&str`. You can do this by using more generics, e.g.

```
fn print_strings(seq: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>) {
    for s in seq {
        let s = s.as_ref();
        println!("- {}", s);
    }
}
```

This requires the `Item` to be something that you can retrieve a `&str` from, and then in your loop `.as_ref()` will return the `&str` you are looking for.

This also has the added bonus that your code will also work with `Vec<String>` and any other type that implements `AsRef<str>`.

Comment: You don't even need to annotate the lifetimes either.

Comment: @harmic Good call.

Comment: Nice that `impl` inside `impl` compiles - I could have sworn that the compiler rejected that (or very similar) construct just the other day!

Comment: @user4815162342 I had the same thought and had to double-check too, maybe that's a more recent change than the top-level `impl` support?

Comment: Thanks! This answer taught me a ton, but the other more directly answers "_must_ Item be generic?" (answer: not necessarily).

Comment: Fair enough, though I'd say given the various calls to `print_strings` that you listed, the answer is yes it must be. I assumed the function call portion was the part that should stay the same.

Comment: Both interpretations made sense given the question, which is why I upvoted your answer _and_ wrote mine. The OP was listing the various calls to `print_strings()` under the impression that they all provided iterators that yield `&str`, and wondered why some of them aren't accepted by the function. Fixing the iterators is as valid as generalizing the function, and the "correct" choice will likely depend on how the function and the call sites look in actual code rather than the stripped-down example.